# How to fix the mismatch of font size of following?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, cases

I want to generate the cases in the picture. However, the Symbols T<sub>1</sub>, T<sub>2</sub> on LHS and RHS are different in size.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools]

\begin{document}

\mbox{}
$$
  (\mathcal{T}_{1},  \mathcal{T}_{2})=
   \begin{cases}
\frac{\left|\mathcal{T}_{1} \cap  \mathcal{T}_{2}\right|}{Min\ 
    {\left|\mathcal{T}_{1}\right|, \left|\mathcal{T}_{2}\right|\} } &  
       negative~test, \\
    -1 & positive~test 
    \end{cases}
$$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried `dcases`?

Comment: By the way, *min* and positive test, as well as negative text should be upright.

Comment: See [Why is `\[` ... `\]` preferable to `$$` ... `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5764)

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 10):

You can either set the `\frac`tion using `\displaystyle` (via `\dfrac`), or use `dcases`. The latter provides a better solution since it results in better vertical spacing.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
  (\mathcal{T}_1, \mathcal{T}_2) = \begin{dcases}
    \frac{| \mathcal{T}_1 \cap \mathcal{T}_2 |}
      {\min\{| \mathcal{T}_1 |, | \mathcal{T}_2 |\}} &  
      \text{negative test}, \\
    -1 & \text{positive test}
  \end{dcases}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: In this case `dcases*` seems appropiate.